# How can I add a default constructor and have it call another constructor and use the default values?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public class NewFrame 
{

    public NewFrame(string iconSource = Const.Car,
        string iconColor = Const.Red)
    {
```

When I try and use it then it's telling me I am missing a default constructor.  How can I add one of these and still make the code use the default values for iconBackgroundColor and IconSource? I thought that adding in those defaults with the = Const. would make it work but it seems like it doesn't think my constructor is a default (with no params).

Comment: `public NewFrame(){}` set the properties as auto implemented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Comment: Are you using a library that requires a default constructor?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are getting an exception. **_Please_**: when you are reporting an error, describe it exactly - in particular say whether it's a runtime or a compile-time error and the exact wordking. In this case (the call to CreateInstance will result in a System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'.  See my _answer_ (which is more of a comment) below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having two optional parameters, you don't actually create 4 different constructor declarations under the hood (one with both parameters, one with the first parameter, one with the second parameter, and one with neither). There is still only one constructor, with two parameters. It's just that C# recognises that the parameters are optional, and has syntactic sugar to let you omit them when you call the constructor.

However, if you use reflection to create an instance of your class (probably whatever the thing that requires a default constructor is doing), and you attempt to invoke the parameterless constructor, it won't find one, because there is no syntactic sugar in reflection.

Here is an example:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = typeof(MainClass);
        object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }

    public MainClass(int a = 10)
    {

    }
}
```

If you use `typeof(MainClass).GetConstructors()`, it will tell you that there is only one.

To actually declare a default constructor, you can do:

```
public class NewFrame 
{

    public NewFrame(string iconSource = Const.Car,
        string iconColor = Const.Red)
    {
        ...
    }

    public NewFrame() : this(Const.Car, Const.Red) {  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You just have to add another empty overload and call the required constructor with defaults. See below:

```
public class NewFrame 
{
    public NewFrame() : this(Const.Car, Const.Red){
    }
    
    public NewFrame(string iconSource,
        string iconColor)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, when I do something like this, I take the route that @VyacheslavBenedichuk's answer is showing.

I'm not sure what your complaint is.  This code compiles for me:

```
public class TestConstructor
{
    public TestConstructor(string what = Const.Car, string color = Const.Red)
    {

    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var tc = new TestConstructor();
    }

    public class Const
    {
        public const string Car = "car";
        public const string Red = "red";
    }
}
```

What do your definitions of `Const.Car` and `Const.Red` look like?  Where are you seeing the error?

But, if you use something that requires a default constructor, then this will not work.  For example, this will fail at runtime:

```
var tc2 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestConstructor));
```

***Please***, when you are reporting an error, describe it exactly - in particular say whether it's a runtime or a compile-time error, the exact wording of the error, and the context in which the error occurs.  In this case (the call to `CreateInstance`) will result in a `System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'`

In this case, you need to follow @VyacheslavBenedichuk's advice